# ComboBox displays wrong value on form load, then sets wrong value to record

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am working on a simple WinForms application in Visual Studio 2019. The application connects to a SQL Server 2017 Express database via Entity Framework.

In the `ModuleMaintenance` form the available "modules" are displayed in a DataGridView, while the other form controls display the contents of the module selected in the grid. When the form initially loads, the combobox does not assume the correct value.

[image: The Module Maintenance Form]

Notes:

1. The Grid display is correct: Module “Nice Butte” is owned by Ross Wise.
2. The other field controls- including the “Owner ID” TextBox are displaying correct data; The MemberID Key for Ross Wise is in fact 1.

**Problem**:

The “Module Owner” combobox is displaying incorrect data. It is displaying the member name that appears first in the `Member` table (sorted by `FirstName, LastName`). Ed, who is `MemberID = 2`, is not the owner of “Nice Butte.”

The code that initializes the combobox is auto-generated:

```
// cbx_ModuleOwnerID
// 
this.cbx_ModuleOwnerID.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.moduleBindingSource, "ModuleOwnerID", true));
this.cbx_ModuleOwnerID.DataSource = this.memberBindingSource;
this.cbx_ModuleOwnerID.DisplayMember = "FullName";
this.cbx_ModuleOwnerID.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Baskerville Old Face", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.cbx_ModuleOwnerID.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(519, 103);
this.cbx_ModuleOwnerID.Name = "cbx_ModuleOwnerID";
this.cbx_ModuleOwnerID.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(215, 26);
this.cbx_ModuleOwnerID.TabIndex = 18;
this.cbx_ModuleOwnerID.ValueMember = "MemberID";
```

The code that initializes the bindingSources is:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    _DBC = new SMRC_DispatcherEntities();

    _DBC.Modules.Load();
    _DBC.Members.Load();

    this.moduleBindingSource.DataSource = _DBC.Modules
                                                .OrderBy(d => d.ModuleName)
                                                .ToList();

    this.memberBindingSource.DataSource = _DBC.Members
                                              .OrderBy(m => m.FirstName)
                                              .ThenBy(m => m.LastName)
                                              .ToList();

    InitializeForm();  // This currently has no contents 

}
```

Further symptoms:

When I move to the next record in the Grid all controls *including* the combobox are updated with correct content:

[image: Moved to second item in the grid]

When I move back to the first record the field controls now correctly display data that has been **inappropriately** changed by the combobox’s bad data:

[image: The WRONG Information gets saved!]

Note that the DataGridView has not been updated, most likely because the change has not been committed to the database yet.

The combobox was configured entirely in Visual Studio’s (2019) Form Designer:

[image: The Binding and List Linking settings for the ComboBox]

I can change the owner of a module and that change is retained:

[image: The ComboBox works normally after the initial load]

I have used comboboxes many times and I have never had this sort of difficulty.

Any ideas?

In response to a request for additional code-
The form's class definition:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Dispatcher
{
    public partial class ModuleMaintenance : Form
    {
        private SMRC_DispatcherEntities _DBC;
        public ModuleMaintenance()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            _DBC = new SMRC_DispatcherEntities();

            _DBC.Modules.Load();
            _DBC.Members.Load();

            this.moduleBindingSource.DataSource = _DBC.Modules
                                                        .OrderBy(d => d.ModuleName)
                                                        .ToList();

            this.memberBindingSource.DataSource = _DBC.Members
                                                      .OrderBy(m => m.FirstName)
                                                      .ThenBy(m => m.LastName)
                                                      .ToList();

            InitializeForm();

        }

        private void InitializeForm()
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Database Context:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Dispatcher
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class SMRC_DispatcherEntities : DbContext
    {
        public SMRC_DispatcherEntities()
            : base("name=SMRC_DispatcherEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Community> Communities { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Industry> Industries { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<IndustrySpot> IndustrySpots { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LayoutDivision> LayoutDivisions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Layout> Layouts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<RollingStockMasterType> RollingStockMasterTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<RollingStockType> RollingStockTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SpotAcceptableCarType> SpotAcceptableCarTypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Modules & Members:

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Dispatcher
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Module
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Module()
        {
            this.Communities = new ObservableListSource<Community>();
            this.LayoutDivisions = new ObservableListSource<LayoutDivision>();
        }

        public int ModuleID { get; set; }
        public string ModuleName { get; set; }
        public int ModuleOwnerID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ModuleCreator { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> HasCrossover { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> LocalLineThrough { get; set; }
        public string ModuleNotes { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ObservableListSource<Community> Communities { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ObservableListSource<LayoutDivision> LayoutDivisions { get; set; }
        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
    }
}

    // <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Dispatcher
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Member
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Member()
        {
            this.Layouts = new ObservableListSource<Layout>();
            this.Modules = new ObservableListSource<Module>();
        }

        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SpouseName { get; set; }
        public string AddressStreet { get; set; }
        public string AddressCity { get; set; }
        public string AddressState { get; set; }
        public string AddressZip { get; set; }
        public string TelephonePrimary { get; set; }
        public string TelephoneSecondary { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public byte MemberSinceMonth { get; set; }
        public short MemberSinceYear { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ObservableListSource<Layout> Layouts { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ObservableListSource<Module> Modules { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Dispatcher
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Member
    {
        public String FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstName + " " + LastName;
            }
        }

        public String MemberSince
        {
            get
            {
                return MemberSinceMonth.ToString("00") + "//" + MemberSinceYear.ToString("####");
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class Layout
    {
        public String DesignerName
        {
            get
            {
                return Member.FullName;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class Module
    {
        public String OwnerName
        {
            get
            {
                return Member.FullName;
            }
        }

    }

 }
```

The Designer's auto-generated code is too long to include here, it is posted on my [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UF7icDDPY3lBZcGzPw020INn0aDn4WvI).

That is everything I am aware of.

Comment: When the form loads, you are displaying details of the first module in textboxes and other controls. Can you share that code?  Are you also setting the ComboBox value to the OwnerId of the Module?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya If there is code involved in those actions I did not write it nor do I know where it is. It is handled by the individual constructors and event handlers of each control via its binding link to the data. All the code that is created for each control by the VS Designer as it is drag-dropped from the DataSource, that I know of, is in the InitializeComponent() method which is where the first block of code in the question came from. I have added the full code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is not an explanation.  I still don't know why the combobox is not provided with current data when the form opens, but the solution (work-around?) is to reset the BindingSource bindings.

The revised OnLoad method:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    _DBC = new SMRC_DispatcherEntities();

    _DBC.Modules.Load();
    _DBC.Members.Load();

    this.moduleBindingSource.DataSource = _DBC.Modules
                                                .OrderBy(d => d.ModuleName)
                                                .ToList();

    this.memberBindingSource.DataSource = _DBC.Members
                                              .OrderBy(m => m.FirstName)
                                              .ThenBy(m => m.LastName)
                                              .ToList();

    InitializeForm();

    moduleBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);   //  <== This fixes the issue!

}
```